# Is it safe to use colossal (999999px) border widths?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a letterbox style transition on my page, where the letterbox shrinks over the content until its fully black, the page changes behind it, then the letterbox grows back to full size to reveal the whole viewport. I'm doing this with a blank div, and using a huge border around it. To save on performance, instead of shrinking the width and height parameters, I'm using a scale transform, which doesn't cause layout shifts.

The issue with this is the border gets scaled too. In order to bring the letterbox down to small enough that it can't be seen any more, I'm tweening it down to a scale factor of ~0.001. In order for the border to be big enough that it doesn't "run out", it has to be a whopping ~999999px. This seems like an ugly solution, but is it ok? Do browsers have a limit on border size? Is it rendering the border in a sane way if I do this?

Comment: "Safe", sure. The best solution, definitely not.

Comment: Please add enough code so that we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [viewport](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/) units instead to accurately cover the screen without excessive sizes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  
  border-top-width: 50vh;
  border-bottom-width: 50vh;
  border-left-width: 50vw;
  border-right-width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow how this works, tweening the scale still causes those borders to shrink, and tweening the viewport units causes layout shifts?

Comment: Could you amend your original question with a code example that can better explain your issue please?